# cassandra query for list the data using timestamp

Tags: cassandra

I am very new to Cassandra. I have one table with the following columns CustomerId, Timestamp, Action,ProductId. I need to select the CustomerId and from date - to date using time stamp.I dont know how to do this in cassandra any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all could you should remember that you should plan what queries will be executed in future and make table keys according to it.
If you have keys as (customerId, date) then your query can be for example:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE customerId= '1' AND date < 1453726670241 AND date > 1453723370048;
```

Please, see http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-cql/cql/cql_using/useAboutCQL.html

Comment: In case if I need to view the set of customers depending upon the product ID means what query I need to use ?

Comment: Cassandra is not relational base, so you can't select all you want. In this case you should make product id as index and use allow filtering command, but it works so slow. There is different methods to solve this issue. One of them - create few of tables with different primary keys and store the same data in different formats. Only select throw primary keys works very fast, so you should plan your future queries and make table keys correctly. For ex. : costomerId -> date -> productId OR productId -> date -> customerId ...